# In Firefox, when printing a page with anchor tags, the link location is printing after the text

Tags: firefox, printing, anchor, href, blueprint-css

For example,

```
<a href="../somepage/page.aspx?qs=asdf">Text Here</a>
```

will print out as...

---

Text Here(../somepage/page.aspx?qs=asdf)

---

In IE, it looks normal (doesn't print the url). Any ideas why this is acting in this fashion?

Comment: It doesn't actually... What ff version are you using?

Comment: This happens on Firefox 26 out of the box. @SteveEynon's answer fixes the issue (or disables the feature).

Comment: Surely there must be some configuration option in the browser itself to disable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was in the css framework we are using (Blueprint). There was the below line in the style file:

```
a:link:after,a:visited:after{content:"(" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%}
```

Guess this might help others who use Blueprint.

Answer (score 27):

Extrapolating from Brett's answer, on Firefox 25, this CSS style removes the offending href:

```css
@media print {
    a:link:after,
    a:visited:after {
        content: "" !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you're using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework, this:

```
a[href]:after{
    content:"";
}
```

... will do the trick! (at least in bootstrap 3)

Comment: I had to add `!important` otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to be more specific - say remove links within a table, then you could do the following with jQuery.

```
$(".tableclass tr td a").removeAttr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your layout page (Master Page)

```
a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the semantic reason to print the url next to the link.
Imagine you print the document without the url. You cannot be sure to completely understand the text as it is meant by the author.

It can be necessary for a quote to print the source as well. That is important i.e. for academic texts.

Indeed Bretts answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem altogether on the screen by including the media attribute on the print style link as follows

```
<link href="../../Content/blueprint/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```